# getting checked checkbox display name

Tags: javascript

I have a set of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="111" name="checkbox"  id="1">india
<input type="checkbox" value="121" name="checkbox" id="21">pak
<input type="checkbox" value="131" name="checkbox" id="31">china
<!-- ... -->
<input type="checkbox" value="141" name="checkbox" id="10">srilanka
```

I want to get the display name of checked check boxes like if india , pak ... I tried with following code which gives me value 111,121, ....

```
    field= document.form.checkbox;
     for(var i=0; i < field.length; i++)
                       {  

                       if(document.getElementById(i).checked==true)
                         Cities+=document.classifiedForm.checkbox[i].value + ",";



                        }
```

Comment: @mu is too short - (1) I think you meant shouldn't start with a number. (2) Since we've gotten our lovely HTML5, IDs can now start with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can set some other some other property in checkbox to be the name of the country, I think you can set it as class,

```
<input type="checkbox" value="111" class="India"  id="1">india
<input type="checkbox" value="121" class="Pak" id="21">pak
```

and in javascript,

```
field= document.form.checkbox;
 for(var i=0; i < field.length; i++)
     {  

       if(document.getElementById(i).checked==true)
               Cities+=document.classifiedForm.checkbox[i].getAttribute("class")+ ",";

    }
```

Comment: Changing the names of the input elements is likely to significantly change how the form works.

Comment: @Jayantha : for getting length im using the name .

Comment: I agree with @JohnFlatness, you should set another attribute, one that is not standard or commonly used.

Comment: Yes, but his name of the check-boxes are all same. He can use some other property like `class` as he want.

Comment: You should probably use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead, as name may be used server side for other purposes.

Comment: @Kiran what do you mean by getting length ? All the names are same?